# How to combine 3 queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and I am trying to pull the records for material specific. So my queries are as follows

**Single Day Query**

```
SELECT tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin, COUNT( product_serial_no ) AS  `S_FTD` 
FROM register_product_claim
INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
WHERE retailer_code =  '9017'
AND register_product_claim.dt =  '2016-08-04'
GROUP BY tm.asin
ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Month Wise**

```
SELECT tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin, COUNT( product_serial_no ) AS  `S_MTD` 
FROM register_product_claim
INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
WHERE retailer_code =  '9017'
AND MONTH( register_product_claim.dt ) =  '08'
GROUP BY tm.asin
ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Qtr Wise**

```
SELECT tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin, COUNT( product_serial_no ) AS  `S_QTD` 
FROM register_product_claim
INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
WHERE retailer_code =  '9017'
AND (
MONTH( register_product_claim.dt ) =  '08'
OR MONTH( register_product_claim.dt ) =  '07'
OR MONTH( register_product_claim.dt ) =  '06'
)
GROUP BY tm.asin
ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**This all works fine.**

Now I am trying to merge all the queries. but unable to merge them I used. Union, Joins, but no luck.

the last one tried was

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin,
        COUNT(product_serial_no) as S_FTD
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND register_product_claim.dt = '2016-08-04'
    GROUP BY tm.asin) as s1  
   Inner Join
    (SELECT 

        COUNT(product_serial_no) as S_MTD
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '08'
    GROUP BY tm.asin) as s2
   Inner Join
    (SELECT 

        COUNT(product_serial_no) as S_QTD
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND (MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '08'
            OR MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '07'
            OR MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '06')
    GROUP BY tm.asin) as s3
```

My Expected output is

```
model_number | item_description |  mrp | asin | S_FTD | S_MTD | S_QTD
```

Where S_FTD is one day, S_MTD is Monthly and S_QTD is Quarterly results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation, adjust this to your code:

```
SELECT t.model_number,t.item_description,t.mrp,t.asin,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.new_col = 'D' then t.S_TD END) as S_FTD,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.new_col = 'M' then t.S_TD END) as S_MTD,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.new_col = 'Q' then t.S_TD END) as S_QTD
FROM (
     SELECT ss.*,'D' as new_col FROM (Daily Query) ss
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ss1.*,'M' FROM (Monthly Query) ss1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ss2.*,'Q' FROM (Quarter Query) ss2
     ) t
GROUP BY t.model_number,t.item_description,t.mrp,t.asin
```

**Note:** You have to alias the column `S_FTD` in the daily query as `S_TD` for this to work.

Comment: I am sorry if this is very basic but I am getting `1054 - Unknown column 't.S_MTD' in 'field list'`

Comment: I don't see `t.S_MTD` in my query, did you change anything? You need to call all the columns `S_FTD,S_MTD,S_QTD` as `S_TD` in the inner queries. The query I wrote addresses `S_TD` and not `S_MTD`

Comment: Also no need to select/union 3 times . Just where register_product_claim.dt between start of quarter (date param) and end of quarter(date param)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **select * from** 
before each individual tables

eg.SELECT *
    FROM (
         **Select * from**
        (SELECT 
            tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin,
            COUNT(product_serial_no) as S_FTD
        FROM
            register_product_claim
        INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
        WHERE
            retailer_code = '9017'
                AND register_product_claim.dt = '2016-08-04'
        GROUP BY tm.asin) as s1
      Union

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     Select * from
    (SELECT 
        tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin,
        COUNT(product_serial_no) as S_FTD
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND register_product_claim.dt = '2016-08-04'
    GROUP BY tm.asin) as s1  
  Union

select * from


    (SELECT 

        COUNT(product_serial_no) as S_MTD
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '08'
    GROUP BY tm.asin) as s2
 Union
Select * from
    (SELECT 

        COUNT(product_serial_no) as S_QTD
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND (MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '08'
            OR MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '07'
            OR MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '06')
    GROUP BY tm.asin) as s3

)
```